# How do I reread ViewContainerRef after I inject it into the DOM

Tags: angular

I can dynamically inject my component if I have the viewContainerRef in the component i.e:
In my component I declare:

```
@ViewChild('parent', {read: ViewContainerRef})
```

And in my template I have

```
<div #parent></div>
```

My aim is to have a table which loops through few dataset. When you click on an item, it should load a component dynamically. The problem I am having is when I click on an element and it adds the viewContainerRef, by this point the component does not know what the **parent** reference is.

Any ideas?

**Full code**

```
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() someData: any;

    @ViewChild('parent', {read: ViewContainerRef})
    parent: ViewContainerRef;
    childComponent= null;
    errorMessage:any;

   constructor (private myService: MyService, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
      this.childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AnotherComponent); 
   }



   //Show child when row clicked
    showChildRow(event:any, trade: Object){
      var tableId = jQuery(event.target).closest('table')[0].id;
      var table = jQuery('#' + tableId).DataTable();
      var tr = jQuery(event.target).closest('tr');
      var row = table.row( tr );

      if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
          // This row is already open - close it
          jQuery('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
          } );
      }
      else {
          // Open this row
          this.myService.callSomeMethod("aaaa", "01-Jan-2015", "01-Jan-2017")
                          .subscribe(
                            data => this.format(data, row, tr),
                            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
                          )

      }
    }

    //Show child when row clicked
    format ( data, row, tr ) {
      var childRow = '<div class="slider col-xs-12">'+
                        '<div #parent></div>';

      row.child(childRow).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
      jQuery('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();

      this.parent.createComponent(this.childComponent, 0);
     component.instance.data= data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like the approach demonstrated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 might work for you.

Comment: Can you explain us what you mean speaking `it adds the viewContainerRef`?

Comment: So when I loop over my array, I have a click event listener. When the user clicks this, I find the current <tr> and add some HTML to it. The HTML I want to add is my viewContainerRef e.g. <div #parent></div>. Then I want create my component. But this doesnt work because #parent is added after the component has been loaded

Comment: just post the entire code, it might help you getting a proper answer

Comment: I've updated my question with my code